# Error on loading csv to SybaseIQ using dbisql

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

I am trying to upload a bunch of csv's to SybaseIQ using dbisql's Load command.
My CSV's look like this

```
"ps,abc","jgh","kyj"
"gh",""jkl","qr,t"
```

and my Load command and other options are these:

```
set temporary option ISQL_LOG = '/path/for/log/file';
set temporary option DATE_ORDER = 'MDY';
Load table test (a, b, c)
Format bcp
Strip RTRIM
Escapes OFF
quotes ON
Delimited by ','
```

I create a '.ctl' file like the one above and then execute it with the following command:

```
dbisql -c "uid = xxx; pwd = yyyy" -host aaaa - port 1089 -nogui test.ctl
```

On execution I get the following error:

```
Non-space text found after ending quote character for an enclosed field.
--(db_RecScanner.cxx 2473)
SQLCODE=-1005014, ODBC 3 state="HY000"
```

**HOWEVER**

It works fine with the following csv format

```
"ps,abc","jgh",kyj
"gh",""jkl",qrt
```

i.e if the last column doesn't have the double quotes it works. but all my files have double quotes around each element.

Also the following .ctl file

```
set temporary option ISQL_LOG = '/path/for/log/file';
set temporary option DATE_ORDER = 'MDY';
Load table test (a ASCII(8), b ASCII(7), c ASCII(7))
Strip RTRIM
Escapes OFF
quotes ON
Delimited by ','
```

is able to insert data as in the first csv sample into the database but it also inserts the quotes and the commas and also messes up the data:

ex: first row in the db would look like

```
"ps,abc"   ,"jgh", "kyj""g
```

as opposed to

```
ps,abc jgh kyj
```

I am going nuts over trying to figure out what the issue is I have read the manual for sybase and dbisql and according to that the first control file should be able to load the data properly, but it doesn't do that. Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Also my table structure is like this:

a(varchar(8)) b(varchar(7)) c(varchar(7))

Comment: Are you creating the CSV on a windows system, and importing on a *nix system?  If so there could be hidden formatting characters at the end of each line, which seems to be the error you are receiving.

Comment: @michael : no the files are being created on unix only and i tested it with the sample files above which i then tested for spaces. It doesnt seem to be the problem.